# linux shell leave spaces in variable

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script which is supposed to create a file and fill two lines on it (to make it simple).

```
echo -e "#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    var1 = ''" > file1.py
```

This does work, but when I try to put file1.py content in a variable, then it shortens spaces and keeps only one space.

```
content="#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    var1 = ''"
echo -e $content > file1.py
```

:( please help

Comment: What do you mean by "shortens spaces and keeps only one space" ?

Comment: I add four spaces before var1 and it removes them and keeps only one space in file1.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before execution the command is resolved to be:

```
echo -e this is what is inside the content variable > file1.py
```

therefore you just have to quote it again:

```
echo -e "$content" > file1.py
```

which results in:

```
echo -e "this is what is inside the content variable" > file1.py
```

Comment: @bilou: the lesson here is to always quote `"$variables"` unless you specifically want the word-splitting effect seen in your question.